# Scroll views outside Grid/ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview, scroll

I can't find the answer to my question because I don't know how to form the right question. With my current code, my gridview has its own scroll and the imageview is fixed (1st link). How can I make it so that the view outside the GridView or ListView moves with it while scrolling? (2nd link).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/llWhI.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/neroJ.png

Comment: Looks like you are looking for a header in a gridview. But a imageview would need some tweaking in existing ilbrarys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these links to library and SO post on header in a gridview:

1. [HeaderGridView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.3_r2.1/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java) //google's solution
2. [StickyGridHeaders](http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/)
3. GridViewHeader
4. [StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders)

Answer (score 0):

use **ScrollView** in the first line of your xml file.